# Udp Packet error rate in omnetpp

Tags: udp, simulation, omnet++

I have a question regarding the error rate calculation in .cc file for udpapp.

```
errorRate = ((float)(numPKTDropped) / (float)(numReceived + numPKTDropped))*100;
EV << "Error rate= "<<errorRate<<"%, Sent= "<<numSent<<" , Received= "<<numReceived<< endl;
```

this is my code and its a duplex system. Udp packet receiver is unaware with the number of sent packets from sender. How could this be possible to know this via code in omnetpp.

Comment: is there anything by which we can do socket binding on the sender side and calculate from there?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest put a sequence number into the UDP payload so you will know on the receiving side if a sequence number is skipped (except the case when the last packets at the end of the simulation are lost). That would be a good enough estimation for the USP packet loss.

Comment: you mean i should do port binding at receiver end? Because udp has no mechanism to detect the number of sent packets. Also how would this sequence number can be implemented?